# LookupAccountName ошибка

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

Не могу разобраться где у меня ошибка. Мне необходимо узнать SID пользователя. Делаю это вот так:

```
VOID AddUserToLocalGroup()
{
   TCHAR *sDomainName = nullptr;
   SID UserSid;
   SID_NAME_USE use_sid;
   DWORD dwSidSize = SECURITY_MAX_SID_SIZE, dwDomainNameSize = 0x00;

   BOOL result;

   if(!LookupAccountName(nullptr, tsName, &UserSid, &dwSidSize, nullptr, &dwDomainNameSize, &use_sid))
   {
       if(GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
       {
           sDomainName = new TCHAR[dwDomainNameSize];
       
           if(sDomainName != nullptr)
           {
               memset(sDomainName, 0x00, dwDomainNameSize * sizeof(TCHAR));

               result = LookupAccountName(nullptr, tsName, &UserSid, &dwSidSize, sDomainName, &dwDomainNameSize, &use_sid);
            
               delete[] sDomainName;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

За первый вызов LookupAccountName, узнаю какой буфер необходим для DomainName и далее выделяю этот буфер и потом второй раз вызываю LookupAccountName. Программа рушится при вызове оператора delete. Начал смотреть, что в адресах...

Вот, выделилась память по определенному адресу, ну и очистилась, соответственно:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После второго вызова LookupAccountName, в место, куда указывает указатель, в памяти, информация об имени домена появилась. А вот в самом указателе, теперь какой то другой непонятный адрес... К слову, в программе по данному адресу ничего нет...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну соответственно, при вызове delete, программа падает, потому-что по этому адресу ничего нет, тут и гадалке не ходи)))
Не понимаю, где ошибка....

Answer (score 0):

Параметр `dwSidSize` при вызове функции должен содержать размер буфера, на который указывает предыдущий аргумент, в байтах. А тут буфер для `SID` (требуемый размер которого изначально не известен) не выделяется, а вместо размера вставлена левая константа `SECURITY_MAX_SID_SIZE`. Соответственно при втором вызове происходит классическое переполнение буфера.

Далее, оператор `new` не может возвращать нулевой указатель, так что проверка `if(sDomainName != nullptr)` бесполезна, а вместо `memset` следовало бы инициализировать массив сразу при выделении.

Comment: З.Ы. Еще не стоит просто так запускать VS в режиме администратора.